# I’m trying to grep value between string and the first space

Tags: regex, grep

I’m trying to grep value between string and the first space.

My file contain lines ex:

```
speed:10 temp_min:-14 temp_max:10 
speed:5 temp_min:-12 temp_max:10
```

I would like to get

```
grep "temp_min" file
-14
-12
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP 'temp_min:\K\S+' file
-14
-12
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk -F 'temp_min:' '{split($2, a, " "); print a[1]}' file
-14
-12
```

Or using `sed:

```
sed 's/.*temp_min:\([^[:blank:]]*\) .*/\1/' file
-14
-12
```

Comment: i'm getting "grep: conflicting matchers specified"

Comment: Your `grep` might not be supporting `-P`, try my awk or sed versions.

Comment: thank you, grep version work correctly, I replace "grep" by "/bin/grep".
for "sed" and "awk", results shows other lines in the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -oP '(?<=temp_min:)[^ ]+' file.
```

If your grep supports `-P` you can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/zM7yV5/14